# Add sufix to field in views

Tags: views

I have a view displaying webform fields (results).

In some questions, the user answered for example 15€, but I added the sufix "€" to the webform so the user won't have to write it. So the answer is just "15".

I want to add the same sufix "€" to the view field so it appears "15€". How can I do this?

Comment: are you talking about views or webform display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the output of any field in a view by using "Rewrite results" and clicking on "Rewrite the output of this field" (see screenshot below). You can use a replacement pattern for the actual content of your field and then add the "€" symbol.

[image]